# Binding to XML data in UWP

Tags: c#, xml, data-binding, uwp

There seems to be no way in UWP to bind to XML data.  In WPF you can do this...

Define a resource...

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="SolarSystem" XPath="SolarSystem/Planets">
    <x:XData>
        <SolarSystem xmlns="">
            <Planets>
                <Planet Name="Mercury" Type="Terrestrial"/>
                <Planet Name="Venus" Type="Terrestrial"/>
                <Planet Name="Earth" Type="Terrestrial"/>
                <Planet Name="Mars" Type="Terrestrial"/>
                <Planet Name="Jupiter" Type="Giant"/>
                <Planet Name="Saturn" Type="Giant"/>
                <Planet Name="Uranus" Type="Giant"/>
                <Planet Name="Neptune" Type="Giant"/>
                <Planet Name="Ceres" Type="Dwarf"/>
                <Planet Name="Pluto" Type="Dwarf"/>
                <Planet Name="Haumea" Type="Dwarf"/>
                <Planet Name="Makemake" Type="Dwarf"/>
                <Planet Name="Eris" Type="Dwarf"/>
            </Planets>
        </SolarSystem>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

Bind XML to a ListView...

```
<ListView Name="ListView5" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SolarSystem},XPath=*}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Cannot seem to do anything remotely similar in UWP.  I can put XML in a file, read it into an XmlDocument...still cannot bind to it.  Cannot seem to bind to anything other than POCO.  Surely I can bind to something other than C# objects.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually put data into a datatable and then bind to the table

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication45
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            foreach(XElement planet in doc.Descendants("Planet"))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                    (string)planet.Attribute("Name"),
                    (string)planet.Attribute("Type")
                });
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: DataTable?  Usually?  DataTable has only recently become available in UWP.  In fact last year I asked Microsoft why DataTable was not in UWP and they told me that no one needs a table in UWP apps!

Comment: Datatables are easy to bind to.  What other object would you like?  Easy enough to load a different object using same technique.

Comment: yes DataTables are great.  I use them all the time in WPF.  However you are really not writing data, you are writing code.  I would argue that DataTables are less elegant and certainly less robust than POCOs.  Imagine a table that has 100's of entries.  You really want to load from a file.  I really want to type data and not code.  I would be happy with XML or JSON or CSV.  Sure you can load XML into your DataTable, but only if you wrote it from the DataTable first.  It is really hard for me to believe you cannot bind to actual data in UWP.  Why is it called "Data Binding" then?

Comment: How can you write code that binds to an unstructured object?  Especially if it is zagged.  Or an object that has lots of multi-layers (recursive).  The easiest type object to bind to is a rectangular object.   CSV is not an object, just a format that can have header rows, can have empty cells, that may contain spaces,tabs and quotes, and can have empty cells.

Comment: There is an explicit or implicit structure to all this data.  XML is structured (in your words, zagged).  CSV (to be usable) has a flat (in your words, rectangular) structure.  In WPF I can bind to all of it.  What I have come to realize is the rich, robust nature of WPF data binding and the relative poverty of its UWP cousin.  Just now I have given up on your DataTable approach because I can't get group headers to work in the LIstVIew.  So I will now stop swimming upstream and write a bunch of POCOs for my data.  Pffffffft.